# Salesforce 1 versus Touch

Tags: salesforce1-app

Can someone please tell me if the new Salesforce 1 product is a replacement for Touch as a mobile app.  Specifically, 'OUT OF THE BOX', without any configuration.  Also curious if the Android version of SF1 is the same, or more limited than the IPAD version.  I would appreciate any and all the insight I can get.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bruce, please read through the release notes for Mobile. Salesforce1 now subsumes Touch. [see link here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile.htm)

*...Salesforce Touch is upgrading to the new Salesforce1 experience. The new app gives you the same Salesforce Touch features you’ve come to expect, in an updated interface that makes it easy for users to find what they need and get their work done faster. On top of that, Salesforce1 gives you more, with many new enhancements*...

Also, re. Android is the same as for iPhone, [see here](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_mobile_salesforce1_requirements.htm)

Comment: Thanks Reaper!  However, on my new Galaxy 3 tablet (android?), the SF1 experience is not very good ... I can't edit any records or fields (or I don't know how to).  Plus the download app ICON is the same as the Chatter Icon, so I'm not sure I have the right app.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Bruce sounds like you have not updated your app to Salesforce1 correctly, your app icon should be Salesforce1 and not chatter-like. I'm not Android-proficient, so I can't say exactly what you should be seeing although it is not much different to the most recent Chatter app except for additional object availability and functionality but generally speaking the interface stays the same. You should be able to select for example a customer record and see the edit button and then be able to edit any field that your permissions allow.

Comment: @Bruce if you're still seeing the old chatter icon it means your on an older android system.  Salesforce1 requires the latest android version and some phones haven't gotten that update yet.  A colleague had to manually upgrade his phone to get it working.

Answer (score 12):

Based on some of the sessions I attended at Dreamforce, Salesforce 1 is the replacement for Touch. Salesforce 1 is a merger of Chatter and Touch. Eventually Touch will reach it's end of life and no longer be supported. As for Android, the Salesforce.com Mobile team focused first on the iOS version of the app, and then the Android version. I don't have an Android device so I don't know how close they really are feature for feature. They did state that both will have the same capabilities. You can checkout http://www.salesforce.com/mobile/sell/ as a starting point.

Comment: I have the android version on my nexus 5.  It doesn't seem lacking at all.  Note that according to the [documentation on the play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en) you need to have at least Jelly Bean (4.2), otherwise you get the old Chatter Mobile when you install.

Answer (score 6):

Salesforce 1 is combines both Salesforce Chatter and Touch into a unified mobile experience with some additional goodies.

If you've upgraded on an android device and you're still seeing the old chatter icon it's likely you're running on a slightly old version of the android OS.  Salesforce 1 requires at least v4.2 (Jelly Bean).

I had a colleague who downloaded Salesforce 1 and noticed it had the old Chatter icon.  After manually upgrading his android os (as his mobile provider hadn't pushed the update yet) he got the full featured Salesforce 1 experience.

Comment: Yup.  You need at least 4.2 (Jelly Bean) which is stated in the Play Store. I actually pulled it up in my mobile browser by going to the /one/one.app URL after logging in through my mobile browser to SFDC. I did this on a Gingerbread phone and was able to see it in some sort of fashion, but that experience is definitely not supported. :-) I now have KitKat on my nexus and it works fabulously.